# Creating accessible list with dividers/subheaders

Tags: html, accessibility

I am trying to determine the best way to create an accessible accordion/list that has sub-headers (or group separators/collapsible headers, if you will).

To illustrate, this is how a default one would look (schematically):

[image]

Some of the items are clickable (and provide a hint to that by changing the background color and changing the cursor) and some are not (like "List item 13").

Some (or all) sub-headers may be collapsible (with some additional hints added later):

[image]

Now, the structure can be implemented in several possible ways:

**Option 1. To hell with standards and accessibility**

```
<ul>
  <div class="header"><a href="...">Header 1</div>
  <li><a href="...">List item 11</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">List item 12</a></li>
  <li><span>List item 13</span></li>
  <div class="header"><a href="...">Header 2</div>
  <li><a href="...">List item 21</a></li>
  <li><span>List item 22</span></li>
</ul>
```

This one does work. It is not accessible and doesn't pass HTML validation, but it works.

**Option 2. Well, at least it passes validator**

```
<ul>
  <li class="header"><a href="...">Header 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">List item 11</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">List item 12</a></li>
  <li><span>List item 13</span></li>
  <li class="header"><a href="...">Header 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="...">List item 21</a></li>
  <li><span>List item 22</span></li>
</ul>
```

This one passes validation and is accessible to an extent, but doesn't allow for distinction (as far as screen readers go) between a header and a regular clickable list item.

**Options 3. TL;DR**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="header" href="...">Header 1</a>
    <ul>      
      <li><a href="...">List item 11</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">List item 12</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a class="header" href="...">Header 2</a>
     <ul>       
       <li><a href="javascript:;">List item 21</a></li>
       <li><span>List item 22</span></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This one, or some more thought-out variation of it seems to be the one. Accessible, as I assume outer or inner bullets should be read properly by a screen reader and passes validation.

It's just a bit more PITA to code and maintain. Both from JS and CSS perspective and especially if it's a plugin that is intended to be extended and customized.

So the question is - which one, if any, of the above would be better. Or, alternatively, what would be the ultimate accordion/list implementation? (which, from my experience, may be a pipe dream)

Comment: Could you give an actual example of the content?

Comment: Well... anything really. List of items where headers are letters the items in the section begin with. Or tasks list with tasks separated into subsections based on priority. Your pick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third option beats the other two by far in terms of accessibility. If the accordion/list did have a lot of content then it may be worth adding headings (`<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc.) to each of the list items. This would provide more semantic structure to the page which would be helpful to users using assistive technology.

```
<h1>Some sections</h1>

<ul>
  <li>
    <h2><a class="header" href="...">Header 1</a></h2>
    <ul>      
      <li><a href="...">List item 11</a></li>
      <li><a href="...">List item 12</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
     <h2><a class="header" href="...">Header 2</a></h2>
     <ul>       
       <li><a href="javascript:;">List item 21</a></li>
       <li>List item 22</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The third option is also the nicest to style and manipulate with JavaScript due to its hierarchical nature.

### Implicit sectioning

There was a discussion about implied and explicit sections in the comments so I thought I would address it. I attempted to download the [HTML5 Outlier Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-outliner/afoibpobokebhgfnknfndkgemglggomo) to test this but unfortunately it didn't seem to show up in the bar. Here is how I understand it:

The sectioning root elements in HTML5 are:

- `<body>`
- `<blockquote>`
- `<details>`
- `<fieldset>`
- `<figure>`
- `<td>`
- `<nav>`
- `<aside>`
- `<footer>`
- `<header>`

Since none of them are present the sections are implicit from the usage of the heading elements much like in HTML4 so the document outline for the markup above would look like this:

1. Some sections

   1.1. Header 1

   1.2. Header 2

This is exactly what we expect and what we want. This is from unor's comment

> It's allowed syntactically. But it would be an issue for the document outline: the start of a new section (→ opening li), introduced by the heading, would still be part of the previous section. If you use the section (or any other sectioning element) expliclty, the start and end of that section is clearly specified.

I believe he's saying that the `<li>` before '1.1. Header 1' would be part of the section '1. Some sections' which is true and I'm my opinion not a problem as the `<li>` should belong to the section above. The usage of a sectioning root element like `<section>` to explicitly define a section block would lead to very much the same result as we had previously:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <section>
      <h2><a class="header" href="...">Header 1</a></h2>
      <ul>      
        <li><a href="...">List item 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">List item 12</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </li>
```

I'm of the opinion (can't find a source) that implicit sectioning is just as 'scoped' as explicit sectioning would be. Since the document outline is a list the `</li>` after the `</section>` in the above would still be part of 1.1 Header 1 according to the document outline like this.

```
<!-- start 1. Some sections -->
<h1>Some sections</h1>

<ul>
  <li>
    <section>
      <!-- start 1.1. Header 1 -->
      <h2><a class="header" href="...">Header 1</a></h2>
      <ul>      
        <li><a href="...">List item 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="...">List item 12</a></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </li>
  <li>
    <!-- end 1.1. Header 1 -->
    <section>
      <!-- start 1.2. Header 2 -->
      <h2><a class="header" href="...">Header 2</a></h2>
      <ul>      
        <li><a href="javascript:;">List item 21</a></li>
        <li>List item 22</li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- end 1. Some sections -->
```

That is to say, once you start a sub-section you cannot end it until you start another section so `</li><li>` would be included at the end of '1.1. Header 1' and also included in its parent section '1. Some sections'.

### References

- [Mozilla Developer - Implicit sectioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document#Implicit_Sectioning)
- [Smashing Magazine - HTML5 And The Document Outlining Algorithm](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/08/16/html5-and-the-document-outlining-algorithm/)
- [HTML5 Doctor - Outlines](http://html5doctor.com/outlines/)

Comment: Note: For HTML5, you should explicitly use `section` then (when using headings in a list).

Comment: @unor Where do you get this from? According to W3C - any flow content, which H2 is, can be `li`'s content. The above is perfectly valid HTML5.

Comment: @ZenMaster: It's allowed syntactically. But it would be an issue for the document outline: the start of a new section (→ opening `li`), introduced by the heading, would still be part of the previous section. If you use the `section` (or any other sectioning element) expliclty, the start and end of that section is clearly specified.

Comment: @unor Not sure I follow. Why would H2 still be a part of previous section if it is in a different flow element?

Comment: @ZenMaster: Not the `h2` element, but the `<li>` which starts the next list item. If you use headings without sectioning elements, *everything* until the next heading begins is part of its implicit section.

Comment: @unor As far as I know the algorithm is a bit more complex than what you present here (since there are implied heading context etc.), but I can't go through it now to validate that. I am going to take your word for it - for now :)

Comment: @Zenmaster: Alright. After all, this is not that relevant for this question. If you should open a dedicated question about this topic in the future, please point me to it :)

Comment: I updated my question with a bit of discussion about what you're talking about. Let me know if you think what I said was incorrect!

Comment: @DanielImms Awesome answer and explanation. It seems, however, that @unor meant the next "outside" `li`, which was what startled me and prompted the better part of the discussion. Accepted.